# What is wrong with my validation for checking that a number is in an array and then changing it so it is different?

Tags: c#, arrays, validation, error-handling, boolean

I am doing a bingo game and want to check if a number has already been called so then if it has a new number is generated that hasnt been called.
 bool[] Numbers;
 Random r;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Numbers = new bool[90];
        this.r = new Random();
        int attempt = this.r.Next(0, 90);

        while (this.Numbers[attempt] == true)
        {
            attempt = this.r.Next(0, 90);
            this.Numbers[attempt] = true;
        }

        textBox1.Text += (attempt + 1).ToString() + " ";
        textcurrent.Text += textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Clear();

    }
```

Comment: You're recreating the array of boolean values on every click.  Any information about which numbers have already been chosen will be lost when the array is recreated.  You need to create the array (or at least save it) outside your button_Click method so that the results are still available for the next click.

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite loop:

```
    while (this.Numbers[attempt] == true)
    {
        attempt = this.r.Next(0, 90);
        this.Numbers[attempt] = true;
    }
```

You have set `this.Numbers[attempt]` to `true` immeadiately before checking whether it is true for continuation of the `while` loop

Comment: That was a miss copy, that should be outside the loop. Even with it outside , numbers still get repeated.

Comment: Actually since `Numbers` is initialized as an array of `bool` all values will be `false` so the `while` doesn't even run once.

Comment: ah - nice catch @juharr. Missed that!

Answer (score 0):

That snippet will result an infinite loop:

```
 while (this.Numbers[attempt] == true)
 {
      attempt = this.r.Next(0, 90);
      this.Numbers[attempt] = true;
 }
```

Notice, that you are setting `this.Numbers[attempt]` to true, and then check if it is `true`, so loop will never end.

I would make an other approach:

```
var notUsed = this.Numbers.Where(used => !used)
                 .Select((val, idx) =>
                      new 
                      {
                          Idx = idx,
                          Val = val
                      }).ToList();

if (!notUsed.Any())
{
    //case when all numbers used
}
else
{
    attempt = notUsed[this.r.Next(0, notUsed.Count)].Idx;
    this.Numbers[attempt] = true;
}
```

EDIT:
The OP in comment said that assignment is done outside loop:

```
 while (this.Numbers[attempt] == true)
 {
      attempt = this.r.Next(0, 90);
 }

 this.Numbers[attempt] = true;
```

Well, in that approach the infite loop can also occur - when all values in array are set to `true`. What's more, you can get `attempt` generated for elements that are set true (when there are many elements set to true, the theoretical chance for getting `false` element is small).

Comment: That was a miss copy, that should be outside the loop. Even with it outside numbers still get repeated

Comment: But it never gets into the loop in the first place since all the values in the array are initialized to `false`.

Comment: @juharr when it is like the OP said (the assigmnet is outside a loop) - it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach.  Create a list of Bingo number and then shuffle it.  Then, just read each number starting at the top:

```
void Main()
{
    //Create a list of BINGO numbers and the shuffle it randomly.
    string letters = "BINGO";
    var bingoNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 75)
                                 .Select(n => string.Format("{0}{1}", letters[(int)Math.Ceiling(n / 15.0) - 1], n))
                                 .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
                                 .ToList();

    foreach (var number in bingoNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);        
    }                            
}
```

The `Math.Ceiling(...)` bit is just a trick to create the array of bingo numbers using Linq.  You could also use two nested `for` loops if you don't want to use Linq.

By using `OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())`, it shuffles the list.  This may not be the best shuffling method.  Others, like the Fisher-Yates might be better.  If you want to use a different shuffling method, you can just omit the `OrderBy` line and shuffle using whatever algorithm you want.

As an aside, I notice you are using 90 for the count of bingo number, but in the traditional game there are only 75.  If you, are not using the traditional BINGO numbers, then you can substitute in the code for the `BINGO` letters and also the range value.